# Rails 6.0 ActiveRecord soft delete overriding default_scope and causing problems with single table inheritance (STI)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti, default-scope

I'm working on a Rails 6.0 application that has the following soft delete ActiveRecord concern defined:

```
module ActiveRecordSoftDeletion
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  
  def self.included(base)
    base.scope :not_deleted, -> { base.unscoped.where(deleted: false) }
    base.send(:default_scope) { base.not_deleted }
    base.scope :only_deleted, -> { base.unscope(where: :deleted).where(deleted: true) }

    def destroy
      self.deleted = true
      self.save(validate: false)
    end

    def recover
      self.deleted = false
      self.save(validate: false)
    end
  end
end
```

The concern has worked fine for a long time and is widely used throughout the application.

Recently we introduced single table inheritance, which was also working fine until we decided to include `ActiveRecordSoftDeletion` to the base class.

Here's an example of my STI classes...

```
class Widget < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveRecordSoftDeletion
end

class Thingy < Widget
end

class Dohicky < Widget
end
```

Before adding `ActiveRecordSoftDeletion` to `Widget`, the code behaved like this...

```
> Thingy.first
SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."type" = $1
ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["type", "Thingy"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

> Dohicky.first
SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."type" = $1
ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["type", "Dohicky"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

The problem is `ActiveRecordSoftDeletion` is **replacing** the default scope. So after including `ActiveRecordSoftDeletion` the queries look like this...

```
> Thingy.first
SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."deleted" = $1
ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["deleted", false], ["LIMIT", 1]]

> Dohicky.first
SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."deleted" = $1
ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["deleted", false], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

I'd like to avoid changing anything in `ActiveRecordSoftDeletion` if possible, since that code is used in many places. But I can't find a way to get the STI classes to add their default scope back.

The documentation for scopes clearly states if you have multiple default scopes they get ANDed together but something about the way the concern is doing things seems to replace the default scope rather than add to it.

Adding the default scope to the STI classes almost works but not quite.

If I change the base class to this...

```
class Widget < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveRecordSoftDeletion
  default_scope { where(type: sti_name) }
end
```

Then all my queries become...

```
SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets"
WHERE "widgets"."deleted" = $1 AND "widgets"."type" = $2
ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $3
[["deleted", false], ["type", "Widget"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

even for the subclasses; they all look for type `Widget`.

Even doing this has the same result...

```
class Widget < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveRecordSoftDeletion
end

class Thingy < Widget
  default_scope { where(type: sti_name) }
end

class Dohicky < Widget
  default_scope { where(type: sti_name) }
end
```

How can I add the correct STI default scope back to the models without changing the soft delete code?

Alternately, how can I update the soft delete code without impacting other models that use the concern?

Comment: If I understood correctly, when you Query
**Thingy.first**, 
the query should be

**SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."deleted" = $1 AND "widgets"."type" = $2 ORDER BY "widgets"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["deleted", false], ["type", "Thingy"], ["LIMIT", 1]]**

Comment: If this is the requirement here, then we can add default scope in child model, i.e in Thingy and Dohicky, like this **default_scope { where(:type => ["Thingy"]) }**  and
**default_scope { where(:type => ["Dohicky"]) }**

Comment: @AbhishekJadav thanks for your comments. The answer you gave should work.  I was hoping there was some way to do what you're suggesting without having to hard code the class name in the default scope.

Comment: i tried with **default_scope { where(:type => [self.to_s]) }** but it didn't work. btw is there any disadvantage of Hardcoding? Generally speaking we use scopes (default or other one) to query with particular conditions. Here we are querying with **type = 'Thingy'** . I m Newbie, needed to understand the disadvantage

Comment: @AbhishekJadav the disadvantage of hard coding is each subclass needs to set the value. That's one more thing the developer could forget to do. It also introduces the potential for human error.  Since we're only talking about 1 line of code I'd say both of those issues are pretty minor but if there's a way to elegantly avoid them all the better!

Comment: gotcha! thanks for giving clarity @doug-couvillion. Btw did you found different solution to this Question?